# Accessing variables in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How can I declare a variable globally in Kotlin such that a variable declared in Class `A` can be accessed in Class `B`?

```
val fpath: Path = Paths.get("")
```

I want to be able to access the variable `fpath` throughout the entire program/project. 
P.S. I am new to Kotlin. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Normally, you pass variables to the things that need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Accessing a property of another class isn’t hard as long as it’s visibility allows it. By default, without explicit visibility modifier, it is:

```
class A{
    val fpath= ...
}

class B(val a: A){
    fun xy() = print(“accessing property of A: ${a.prop}”)
}
```

Second: What you should rather do with your example variable `fpath` is defining it as a top-level element, i.e. directly in a file, which can be accessed from anywhere else by simply importing the element.

For example, you could have a `Common.kt` file in package `com.x` with `fpath = Paths.get(...)` in it. From another file you do `import com.x.fpath` and use it throughout the file.

Third: You could also define the variable in a `companion object` of `A` if it belongs there:

```
class A {
    companion object {
        val fpath = ...
    }
}

class B{
    fun xy() = print(“accessing property of A: ${A.fpath}”)
}
```